# how to change columns name to row values

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, unpivot

I am have a table like below

`Company        jan_value        feb_value`

`sony             10                    20`

I wan to get a result like below

`company              value1                       value2`

`sony                    jan_value                     10`

`sony                     feb_value                    20`

I was trying to us unpivot  but my sql does not support unpivot option since it is google sql.
i really need help on this. thank you in advance

Comment: Seriously consider revising your schema

Answer (score 1):

In SQL in general, you can use `union all`:

```
select company, 'jan_value' as value1, jan_value as value2
from t
union all
select company, 'feb_value' as value1, feb_value as value2
from t;
```

There may be more efficient methods depending on your database.  GCP supports multiple databases.